# What are the directories I see when I hit tab on `cd ~` that are not seen in `ls ~`

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, unix, zsh

When I hit tab on `cd ~`, I see a lost of directories starting with `_` so something like `_dirName` which are not see when I list `ls ~`. I also see `myUsername`, `root`, `daemon`, `nobody`, `Guest` directories. What are all these and what is the difference when using `cd ~/` which seem to list the files that are listed by `ls ~`.

Also, is there a way to `ls` command to list those directories?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you typing `ls ~` then Tab with no whitespace or just `ls ~` then Return?

Comment: @Allan I was typing `ls ~` then Return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This falls under the concept of [parameter expansion in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) and [filename expansion in Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) (essentially the same thing).  Basically, there are two conditions:

- the tilde as the beginning part of a word
- the tilde as a character by itself

If used as the latter, it refers to the `HOME` variable.  When you type `ls ~` followed by <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd> with no whitespace, you’re listing the directory `~` expands to; typically HOME.

When you type a `cd ~` followed by a <kbd>Tab</kbd>  (assuming no whitespace in between), it treats it as part of the filename.  Zsh is trying to “guess” what you could want; it’s no longer treating it as a singular character.  Since it has no clue, it’s giving you what it “thinks” could be possibilities.

To focus it on the HOME directory (assuming that’s what you want) use a `/`.  Exampe: `cd ~/` then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  That will delineate between expanding `~` as the HOME variable or `~` as part of the filename.

In the end, `ls ~` isn’t “hiding” directories from you (to see hidden files use `ls -a`). What you’re seeing is Zsh’s guesses from the builtin Tab completion function

Comment: Why is that the results are same irrespective of my current working directory when using `cd ~` or `ls ~` and Tab?

Comment: Zsh's "guesses" (as you call them) are valid completions and they do refer to real directories.

Comment: @darthV The results are the same because zsh is expanding the _list of other users’ home directories_. It’s not “doing a bad job at guessing”. See the other (more correct) answer

Answer (score 5):

`~` alone expands to your own home directory. There is *also* a syntax `~username` that expands to the home directory of a given username. So if `myUsername` is my username, then `~myUsername` is the same as `~`, and expands to `/Users/myUsername`. Meanwhile, `~root` expands to `root`'s home directory, which (on my system) is `/var/root`. Most of the other possibilities, like `~nobody`, seem to go to `/var/empty`.

The big list of names you are seeing are when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `cd ~` is simply a list of usernames on your system. You can complete the line with any of the usernames and the resulting `cd` command will (try to) take you to that user's home directory. Since the directories `~root`, `~nobody` etc. are not in *your* `~`, it is no surprise that `ls ~` doesn't show them.

Note that it is typical for there to be many more "users" on a system than actual human users, since, for security reasons, it is often beneficial to run programs or services as their own user. Since programs can't access things their users don't have permissions for, this keeps programs from touching things they shouldn't.